# reactive form custom validators not displaying the error in angular6

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

In this demo i have created a sample form for custom validator,
here i have From date and TO date and from time and To time,
working fine:
For from date and to date validation working fine and showing error messages.

problem:
when **choosing same date , eg) july 21 2018 as from date and same in To dat**e and In **from Time be 4:00 Am and To Time be 3:00AM,** the condition gets satisfied, but which is not showing an error message.Somethis went wrong in implementation,can anyone help me to solve appreciated

In html i have given validation message but which gets not displayed.

```
To Time:
<input type="time" formControlName="ToTime">
    <mat-error *ngIf="DaterForm.get('ToTime').hasError('InValidToTime')">FromTime Should be less than ToTime if choose a same date</mat-error>
```

In component:

```
 DaterForm : FormGroup;

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
}
   ngOnInit(){

 this.DaterForm = this.fb.group(
{
  FromDate:['',[AppCustomDirective.fromDateValidator]], // validation working fine
  FromTime:[''],
  ToDate:['',[AppCustomDirective.ToDateValidator]],// validation working fine
  ToTime:['']
},{validator:[AppCustomDirective.timeValidator] // validation not working
}
```

Custom validation:

```
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppCustomDirective extends Validators{

   static fromDateValidator(fdValue: FormControl) {
    const date = fdValue.value;
    console.log('x');
    if (date ===null || date==='') return { requiredFromDate: true };

  }

   static ToDateValidator(todValue: FormControl) {
    const date = todValue.value;

    if (date ===null || date==='') return { requiredToDate: true };

  }


  static timeValidator(formGroupValues: FormGroup): any {
    debugger;
    console.log(formGroupValues);
    const FromDate = formGroupValues.get('FromDate').value;
    const ToDate = formGroupValues.get('ToDate').value;
    const FromTime = formGroupValues.get('FromTime').value;
    const ToTime = formGroupValues.get('ToTime').value;

    if (FromDate.toString() === ToDate.toString()) {
      let fromTime = [];
      let toTime = [];
      fromTime = FromTime.split(':');
      toTime = ToTime.split(':');
      if (parseInt(fromTime[0]) > parseInt(toTime[0])){
      alert("condition satisfied not return any error message");
         return { InValidToTime: true };
        }
      else if (
        parseInt(fromTime[0]) === parseInt(toTime[0]) &&
        parseInt(fromTime[1]) > parseInt(toTime[1])
      ){  alert("condition satisfied not return any error message")
        return { InValidToTime: true };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator?file=app%2Fapp.validators.ts)

Comment: `' InValidToTime'`: remove this leading space. There might be other problems, but I stopped reading at that point.

Comment: @JBNizet that is typo while pasting , i think which is an  implementation issue while return error,if you want  to look the demo see here`https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because you are setting errors on your **form** while you expect for error to be on particular input.

Changing to `<mat-error *ngIf="DaterForm.hasError('InValidToTime')">` Fixes the issue.

FYI this is not how `mat-error` is designed to be used with `<input matInput/>`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-1fu5vx?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: @why error which is not working when move the mat-error inside mat-form-field `<mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf="DaterForm.get('ToDate').hasError('requiredToDate')">Please provide a valid Todate</mat-error>` when move after mat-form field which is working

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-dhcmd4?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: Its because you are using it wrong way. It is designed to display errors of particular input. Input must be in error state (have not null errors) or mat-error will be hidden. Its not ngIf in controll of WHEN error is displayed (inside matInput) but controll state. This is forked example wit forcibly "fixed" issue, but it is not how mat-error should be use. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-xksspd?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html . You can read Angular Material documentaion on examples to see how to properly handle and show input errors (with animations etc).